# SQL operation to find left join in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have three models in my Rails project. A `User` model, `Hunt` model and a `UserHunt` model  which handles the relationship between two models.

```
class Hunt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_hunts
end
class UserHunt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hunt
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunts
  has_many :user_hunts
end
```

A user can see different hunts on their feed and either accept or reject it. This will create a record on `UserHunt` table. I would like to load new `Hunt` objects to feed which the user hasnt seen. Lets take the `user_id` of the current user as 1. I tried the queries below. But that's not working.

```
Hunt.left_outer_joins(:user_hunts).where.not('user_hunts.user_id = 1')
Hunt.includes(:user_hunts).where.not(user_hunts: {user_id: 1})
```

Even though they do left outer join, it is not showing Hunts which doesnt have an associated object in `UserHunt` model. Which is the best way to query database for hunts that the user hasnt seen ( `user_id` is not 1 in `UserHunt` table or their is no `UserHunt` table record ) ?

Comment: `Hunt.includes(:user).where.not(users: { id: 1 })`?

Comment: No. This would return ``Hunts`` which are not posted by ``user 1`` . What I want is ``Hunts`` on ``left outer join`` with ``UserHunt``  which doesnt have `` 'user_hunts.user_id=1' `` or ``Hunts`` which doesnt have have an associated row  in ``UserHunt``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a small addition to above query to make it work

```
Hunt.left_outer_joins(:user_hunts).where.not('user_hunts.user_id = ? AND user_hunts.user_id is not null',1)
```

It doesnt make sense to add the `not null` condition in the `where` clause but it works as expected.